# Getting NaN instead of value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, nan

I've been working on some Javascript code to perform some math operations on an HTML table. It first calculates an average for a row and then calculates the total of the average for all rows with the same selection from a menu.

The average calculation is working correctly but I've broken something with the total of the averages. I've setup a sample JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/fmdataweb/c4gJU/3/

If you select "moderate" as the risk from the menu and enter some numbers for the Hours Per Week and Weeks Per Year it will calculate the average, but it should then put the average into the Total of Moderate cell. Same if you changed the menu selection to "high".

Appreciate if someone can point out where I'm going wrong - I'm a Javascript newbie at this stage.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The selector `$('#lastYear tr:has(.risk)').eq(i).find('td:last input')`is not matching any element.

**TEST**:

If you insert the line `alert($('#lastYear tr:has(.risk)').eq(i).find('td:last input').length)` below the line `var qty = parseFloat(...)` the pop up window will display `0`.

**EDIT**:

```
var qty = parseFloat($('#lastYear tr:has(.risk)').eq(i).find('td:last').prev().find('input').val());
```

As @Diego pointed out, your original code is matching a cell having a button, not an `input`. The code above selects the cell before the last one and then gets its input. However I'd recommend you using custom classes or id's to make your selector shorter and easier to read.

Comment: Hi - thanks for that. I'm not sure what the issue here is though or what I need to do to resolve it, i.e. why is it not matching any element?

Comment: It doesn't match any element because the last TD doesn't contain an input field, but an anchor.

Comment: To be more specific, `td:last` will match the following element, in your case: `<td class="button mt5" ><a href="#" id="newLastYearRowButton">Add another activity</a></td>`, which is after the TD that contains the input field. Therefore, the TD you're looking is not the last, but the second to last. I'd strongly recommend to simplify your selectors and use identifiers for these elements, instead of looking by position (which is rarely a good thing).

Comment: Thanks very much Claudix and Diego - I see what the problem was now.

Comment: If I wanted to change this to use ID's (which I prefer) can you give me an example of what the syntax would like in this particular example?

Comment: Imagine the `input` you want to match has `id="foo"`. Then, you should simply do: `var qty = parseFloat($('#lastYear tr:has(.risk)').eq(i).find('#foo').val());`. But if you plan to have several "foo" inputs, then you should use a custom class (example: `fooclass`, and do: `var qty = parseFloat($('#lastYear tr:has(.risk)').eq(i).find('.fooclass').val());`. Combinations are infinite and it all depends on what you want to eventually do.

Comment: Thanks Claudix for that explanation - I'm learning as I go so really appreciate your help.